# Sectioning of page

Tags: formatting, minipage

I create this document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0.2cm}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\scriptsize}{\zerodisplayskips}


\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{-0.1cm}}m{#1}}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \centering\underline{\bfseries{\LARGE Nietverbindungen}}\\
    \vspace*{0.3cm}
    \small Zusätzliche Sicherheitsvielfache bei Nietverbindungen aufgrund von Spannungskonzentration an Nietlöchern:\\
    $j_{s1} = 1,15; \text{ Sitze, Liegebetten, Gurte: } j_{s2} = 1,33; \text{ Gussbauteile: } j_{s3} = 1,25$\\

    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \centering \uline{\bfseries{Schubbelastung}}\\

    \vspace{0.3cm}

    \noindent{\footnotesize
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        1.~\underline{Blechdicke}
        \[\frac{d}{s} < 5,5 \Longleftrightarrow s > \frac{d}{5,5}\]
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        2.~\underline{Abscheren des Niets}
        \[P_B \le P_V = Rc \cdot  \dfrac{d_R^2 \pi}{4} \cdot n \cdot m\]
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        3.~\underline{Ausreißen durch Scherbruch}
        \[P_B \le P_V = 2 \cdot e \cdot s \cdot R_C\vphantom{\frac{d^2_R}{4}}\]
    \end{minipage}\hfill\\}

    \noindent
    {\scriptsize
    %\fontsize{6pt}{6.1pt}\selectfont
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        \begin{align*}
            d & = \text{Nietdurchmesser}\\
            s & = \text{Minimale Blechdicke}\\
        \end{align*}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.07\textheight]{schub.png}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit}\\
            d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
            & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
            & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ (Vollniet)}\\
            n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
            m   & =  \text{Schnittigkeit}\\
        \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            e   & =  \text{Randabstand}\\
            s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
            R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        \end{align*}     
    \end{minipage}\hfill}

    {\footnotesize
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        \centering
        4.~\underline{Ausreißen durch Spalten}
        \[P_B \le P_V = \left(e-\frac{d}{2}\right) \cdot s \cdot \min
        \begin{cases}
        R_m\\
        1,5 \cdot R_{p0,2}\\
        \end{cases}\]
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.62\linewidth}\centering
        \centering
        5.~\underline{Lochleibung {\bfseries {(Universalniete)}}}
        \[P_B \le P_V = d_R \cdot s \cdot n \cdot \min
        \begin{cases}
        \sigma_{LB}\\
        1,5 \cdot \sigma_{L2}\\
        \end{cases}\]
    \end{minipage}}\hfill

    {\scriptsize
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            e   & =  \text{Randabstand}\\
            d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
            s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
            R_M & =  \text{Bruchfestigkeit (Zug)}\\
            R_{p0,2} & = \text{Dehngrenze}\\
        \end{align*}        
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
            & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
            & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ (Vollniet)}\\
            s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
            n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
        \end{align*}        
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            \sigma_{L} & =  \text{Lochleibungsspannung}\\
            \sigma_{LB} & =  \text{Lochleibungsfestigkeit}\\
            \sigma_{L2} & = \text{Lochleibungsgrenze} %
            \end{align*}
             {\small \hspace{2.1cm} \uline{Beachte:} %
            \begin{align*}
                P_B & = j \cdot j_s \cdot P_S \text{ \hspace{0.5cm}\uline{\textit{\bfseries \footnotesize oder}}}\\
                P_B & = d_R \cdot s \cdot n \cdot \sigma_L\\
            \end{align*}}
    \end{minipage}}\hfill

    {\footnotesize 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        5.~\underline{Lochleibung \bfseries{(Senkniete)}}
    \begin{align*}
        P_B \le P_{V,LB}  & = P_{V,LB1} + P_{V,LB2} \\ 
        P_{V,LB1} & = d_R \cdot (s-t) \cdot  \sigma_{min} \\
        P_{V,LB2} & = d_R \cdot t \cdot \alpha \cdot  \sigma_{min}
    \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \vfill
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.06\textheight]{senkschub.png}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
            \underline{\bfseries Nietrechnungstabelle}\\
            \vspace{0.3cm}
            \textcolor{blue}{Lochleibung Dimensionierend}\\
            \textcolor{red}{Abscheren Dimensionierend}\\
            \textcolor{green}{Zu Geringe Blechdicke}
    \end{minipage}}\hfill

    {\scriptsize
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_{V,LB} & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            P_{V,LB1}   & =  \text{Zylindrischer Teil}\\
            P_{V,LB2}   & =  \text{Konischer Teil} \\
            s & = \text{Blechdicke}\\
            t & = \text{Senktiefe}\\
            \alpha & = \text{Abminderungsfaktor}\\
            d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
            & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
            & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ (Vollniet)}\\
            \alpha & = \text{Abminderungsfaktor}
        \end{align*}     
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \centering
        \vfill
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.128\textheight]{abminderungsfaktor.png}
        \[\sigma_{min} = \min 
        \begin{cases}
        \sigma_{LB}\\
        1,5 \cdot \sigma_{L2}
        \end{cases}\]
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \vfill
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth, height=0.167\textheight]{tabelle.png}
    \end{minipage}\hfill


\end{document}
```

The  images and their names can be downloaded [Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuFdA.jpg)

For reference, here is what the document currently looks like:
[image]

Now, I'd like to know if there is a way to structure it into sections, e. g. by using lines to separate the individual parts from each other. I assume that this would help readability, which is important as this is going to be used in exams.

On a side node (not the primary concern of this question): Is it possible to align all equal signs in a straight column spanning multiple rows of minipages? I used the same scaling for all of them, but it appears as this isn't doing the trick.

Any further suggestions in relation to the layout/code would also be very welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do pretty much anything with a `tikzpicture` in combination with `[remember picture,overlay]` (or without it, but it does make things pretty easy). It does come with some drawbacks though, for example, as soon as your document spans multiple pages, things get tricky because you have to manually partition content between pages. But for truly fine-tuning a single-page document, I have found it to be quite handy. If the constraints of such a solution would not be a problem, and if nobody else has posted something better by then, I could try this tomorrow (3am here now ;-)).

Comment: You could also put the content of the minipages inside simple `tcolorbox` blocks.

Comment: @alpenwasser Thanks for the suggestion, I already thought about using tikz but quickly dismissed the idea as I didn't know that you could create overlays with it. I would really appreciate it if you could gibe an example on how to implement in my case, as it seems to be a bit more potent solution than Mike's.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanky, I've thought about that as well but unfortunately this isn't quiet giving me the result I want.

Comment: @Skydiver Alright, I've played around a bit, and there was something I overlooked: the environments (`align*` & Co.) do not play nice at all with tikz nodes. I actually think Johannes' solution via tcolorbox might be a much better idea.
If the aesthetics are a bit too dominating (it would probably look similar to Ross' solution below), you can make the boxes more subdued via the `colback`, `colframe`, `colbacktitle`and `coltitle` parameters so they look more subtle. The default corner radius can also be removed via `arc=0mm`, if you'd prefer that.

Comment: Aligning all equal signs is something you should forget very quickly. It just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

A primitive but effective approach would be to use `\vrule` and `\hrule` for this. You can put `\hfill\vrule\hfill` between the minipages to get a vertical line between them. But caution, you have to use `\hfill` twice, even if there should be no line to get the adjustment right.

For the horizontal lines I added some additional vertical space, because otherwise the line would be too close to the following text.

You can add color by writing `{\color{gray}\hrule}`.

Note: I removed the `\hfill` at the end of each minipage row and adjusted the width of the two column minipage (5.). Also, there are a little gaps in the vertical lines (between equations and legends).

Of course with TikZ you can do much more, but since I'm not familiar with it, I can't help you there.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0.2cm}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}
\appto{\scriptsize}{\zerodisplayskips}


\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{-0.1cm}}m{#1}}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \centering\underline{\bfseries{\LARGE Nietverbindungen}}\\
    \vspace*{0.3cm}
    \small Zusätzliche Sicherheitsvielfache bei Nietverbindungen aufgrund von Spannungskonzentration an Nietlöchern:\\
    $j_{s1} = 1,15; \text{ Sitze, Liegebetten, Gurte: } j_{s2} = 1,33; \text{ Gussbauteile: } j_{s3} = 1,25$\\

    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \centering \uline{\bfseries{Schubbelastung}}\\

    \vspace{0.3cm}

    \noindent{\footnotesize
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        1.~\underline{Blechdicke}
        \[\frac{d}{s} < 5,5 \Longleftrightarrow s > \frac{d}{5,5}\]
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        2.~\underline{Abscheren des Niets}
        \[P_B \le P_V = Rc \cdot  \dfrac{d_R^2 \pi}{4} \cdot n \cdot m\]
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        3.~\underline{Ausreißen durch Scherbruch}
        \[P_B \le P_V = 2 \cdot e \cdot s \cdot R_C\vphantom{\frac{d^2_R}{4}}\]
    \end{minipage}}

    \noindent
    {\scriptsize
    %\fontsize{6pt}{6.1pt}\selectfont
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        \begin{align*}
            d & = \text{Nietdurchmesser}\\
            s & = \text{Minimale Blechdicke}\\
        \end{align*}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.07\textheight]{schub.png}
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit}\\
            d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
            & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
            & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ (Vollniet)}\\
            n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
            m   & =  \text{Schnittigkeit}\\
        \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            e   & =  \text{Randabstand}\\
            s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
            R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        \end{align*}     
    \end{minipage}}

    \vspace{1ex}\hrule\vspace{1ex}

    {\footnotesize
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        \centering
        4.~\underline{Ausreißen durch Spalten}
        \[P_B \le P_V = \left(e-\frac{d}{2}\right) \cdot s \cdot \min
        \begin{cases}
        R_m\\
        1,5 \cdot R_{p0,2}\\
        \end{cases}\]
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.655\linewidth}\centering
        \centering
        5.~\underline{Lochleibung {\bfseries {(Universalniete)}}}
        \[P_B \le P_V = d_R \cdot s \cdot n \cdot \min
        \begin{cases}
        \sigma_{LB}\\
        1,5 \cdot \sigma_{L2}\\
        \end{cases}\]
    \end{minipage}}

    {\scriptsize
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            e   & =  \text{Randabstand}\\
            d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
            s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
            R_M & =  \text{Bruchfestigkeit (Zug)}\\
            R_{p0,2} & = \text{Dehngrenze}\\
        \end{align*}        
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
            & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
            & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ (Vollniet)}\\
            s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
            n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
        \end{align*}        
    \end{minipage}\hfill\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
            \sigma_{L} & =  \text{Lochleibungsspannung}\\
            \sigma_{LB} & =  \text{Lochleibungsfestigkeit}\\
            \sigma_{L2} & = \text{Lochleibungsgrenze} %
            \end{align*}
             {\small \hspace{2.1cm} \uline{Beachte:} %
            \begin{align*}
                P_B & = j \cdot j_s \cdot P_S \text{ \hspace{0.5cm}\uline{\textit{\bfseries \footnotesize oder}}}\\
                P_B & = d_R \cdot s \cdot n \cdot \sigma_L\\
            \end{align*}}
    \end{minipage}}

    \vspace{1ex}\hrule\vspace{1ex}

    {\footnotesize 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        5.~\underline{Lochleibung \bfseries{(Senkniete)}}
    \begin{align*}
        P_B \le P_{V,LB}  & = P_{V,LB1} + P_{V,LB2} \\ 
        P_{V,LB1} & = d_R \cdot (s-t) \cdot  \sigma_{min} \\
        P_{V,LB2} & = d_R \cdot t \cdot \alpha \cdot  \sigma_{min}
    \end{align*}
    \end{minipage}\hfill\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \vfill
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.06\textheight]{senkschub.png}
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
            \underline{\bfseries Nietrechnungstabelle}\\
            \vspace{0.3cm}
            \textcolor{blue}{Lochleibung Dimensionierend}\\
            \textcolor{red}{Abscheren Dimensionierend}\\
            \textcolor{green}{Zu Geringe Blechdicke}
    \end{minipage}}

    {\scriptsize
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_{V,LB} & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            P_{V,LB1}   & =  \text{Zylindrischer Teil}\\
            P_{V,LB2}   & =  \text{Konischer Teil} \\
            s & = \text{Blechdicke}\\
            t & = \text{Senktiefe}\\
            \alpha & = \text{Abminderungsfaktor}\\
            d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
            & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
            & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ (Vollniet)}\\
            \alpha & = \text{Abminderungsfaktor}
        \end{align*}     
    \end{minipage}\hfill\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \centering
        \vfill
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.128\textheight]{abminderungsfaktor.png}
        \[\sigma_{min} = \min 
        \begin{cases}
        \sigma_{LB}\\
        1,5 \cdot \sigma_{L2}
        \end{cases}\]
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}
        \vfill
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth, height=0.167\textheight]{tabelle.png}
    \end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun and to practice using the `baposter` class (which is available [here](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/)). `baposter` uses `posterbox` to arrange rows and columns of boxes of content. A maximum of six columns can be specified. Any number of rows can be used, as this depends on the height of the boxes. `baposter`a good option when a symmetrical layout is required. `posterbox` can contain any environment (I think) so here I retained some of the `minipages` and also used `tcolorbox` inside two of the `posterbox`.

A couple of things to watch out for. First, `baposter` expects all the header information such as the title and authors. I blended the title into the background just by setting the `textcolor` the same as the background color. Second, alignment of headers in a `posterbox` depends on the box format. I avoided renewing some of the commands by setting `boxheaderheight=0em`, and then just using `tcolorbox` to get centered titles.

My apologies to the OP if I corrupted some of the questions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,portrait,fontscale=1.5]{baposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Input encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Required for accented characters
\usepackage{graphicx}    % Required for including images
\usepackage{multicol}    % To demonstrate placement of example images across 2 columns
\usepackage{wrapfig}     % To demonstrate wrapping text around image
\usepackage{adjustbox}   % To demonstrate wrapping text around image
\usepackage{multirow}    % To demonstrate placement of example images across 2 rows
\usepackage{enumitem}    % To create customized list environment 
\usepackage{blindtext}   % Dummy text
\usepackage{arev}        % Sans serif font with heavy weight
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

%\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
%    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0.2cm}%
%    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
%    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
%    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}}
%\appto{\normalsize}{\zerodisplayskips}
%\appto{\small}{\zerodisplayskips}
%\appto{\footnotesize}{\zerodisplayskips}
%\appto{\scriptsize}{\zerodisplayskips}


\begin{document}

    \background{% this is a user specified background i.e. set background=user in general options (row 32 of code)
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        %the poster background color
        \fill[fill=gray!10!white] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \begin{poster}{
            %general options for the poster
            grid=false,
            columns=3, % how many columns 1-6
            colspacing=5.0mm, % spacing between the columns
            headerheight=0cm, % the height of the header as a proportion of the page height
            background=user, %user or none or plain
            eyecatcher=false, %turn logos on/off
            %posterbox options
            headerborder=closed, % see the baposter manual for the rest
            borderColor=darkgray,
            headershape=rectangle,
            headershade=plain,
            headerColorOne=darkgray,
            textborder=rectangle,
            boxshade=plain,
            boxColorOne=white,
            headerFontColor=white,
            headerfont=\large\bfseries,
            linewidth=1pt
        }
        %Do not change the layout of the following items, although title and author can span multiple lines
        {%left logo
        } 
        {\textcolor{gray!10!white}{dummy}} %the poster title - there must be an entry here.
        {%the author(s) 
        }      
        {%right logo
        } 


        \begin{posterbox}[name=box2,span=3,column=0,row=0,boxheaderheight=0em,borderColor=gray!10!white]{ }%
            \begin{tcolorbox}[colbacktitle=darkgray,halign title=center,sharp corners=all,fonttitle=\bfseries,
                title=Nietverbindungen]
                \centering
                Zusätzliche Sicherheitsvielfache bei Nietverbindungen aufgrund von Spannungskonzentration an Nietlöchern:\\
                $j_{s1} = 1,15; \text{ Sitze, Liegebetten, Gurte: } j_{s2} = 1,33; \text{ Gussbauteile: } j_{s3} = 1,25$\\
            \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{posterbox}

    \begin{posterbox}[name=box3,span=1,column=1,below=box2,boxheaderheight=0em,borderColor=gray!10!white]{}
        \begin{center} \uline{\bfseries{Schubbelastung}} \end{center}
    \end{posterbox}


    \begin{posterbox}[name=box4,span=1,column=0,below=box3,boxheaderheight=2em]{1. Blechdicke}
        \begin{align*}
        \frac{d}{s} &< 5,5 \Longleftrightarrow s > \frac{d}{5,5}\\
        \text{where} & \\
        d & = \text{Nietdurchmesser}\\
        s & = \text{Minimale Blechdicke}
        \end{align*}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.08\textheight]{example-image-a}
    \end{posterbox}

    \begin{posterbox}[name=box5,span=1,column=1,below=box3,bottomaligned=box4,boxheaderheight=2em]{2. Abscheren des Niets}
        \begin{align*}
        P_B \le P_V &= Rc \cdot  \dfrac{d_R^2 \pi}{4} \cdot n \cdot m \\
        \text{where} & \\
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit}\\
        d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
        & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
        & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ (Vollniet)}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
        m   & =  \text{Schnittigkeit}
        \end{align*}
    \end{posterbox}

    \begin{posterbox}[name=box6,span=1,column=2,below=box3,bottomaligned=box4,boxheaderheight=2em]{3. Ausreißen durch Scherbruch}
        \begin{align*}
        P_B \le P_V &= 2 \cdot e \cdot s \cdot R_C\vphantom{\frac{d^2_R}{4}} \\
        \text{where} & \\
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}
        \end{align*}  
    \end{posterbox}

    \begin{posterbox}[name=box7,span=1,column=0,below=box4,boxheaderheight=2em]{4. Ausreißen durch Spalten}
        \begin{align*}
         P_B \le P_V &= \left(e-\frac{d}{2}\right) \cdot s \cdot \min 
        \begin{cases}
        R_m\\
        1,5 \cdot R_{p0,2}\\
        \end{cases} 
        & \\
        \text{where} & \\
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_M & =  \text{Bruchfestigkeit (Zug)}\\
        R_{p0,2} & = \text{Dehngrenze}
        \end{align*} 
    \end{posterbox}

    \begin{posterbox}[name=box8,span=2,column=1,below=box5,bottomaligned=box7,boxheaderheight=2em]{5. Lochleibung {\bfseries {(Universalniete)}}}
        \[P_B \le P_V = d_R \cdot s \cdot n \cdot \min
        \begin{cases}
        \sigma_{LB}\\
        1,5 \cdot \sigma_{L2}\\
        \end{cases}\]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth} % Now 0.5 the box width
            \begin{align*}
            \text{where} & \\
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
            & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
            & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ (Vollniet)}\\
            s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
            n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}
            \end{align*}        
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth} % Now 0.5 the box width
        \begin{align*}
        & \\
        \sigma_{L} & =  \text{Lochleibungsspannung}\\
        \sigma_{LB} & =  \text{Lochleibungsfestigkeit}\\
        \sigma_{L2} & = \text{Lochleibungsgrenze} %
        \end{align*}
        {\small \hspace{2.1cm} \uline{Beachte:} %
            \begin{align*}
            P_B & = j \cdot j_s \cdot P_S \text{ \hspace{0.5cm}\uline{\textit{\bfseries \footnotesize oder}}}\\
            P_B & = d_R \cdot s \cdot n \cdot \sigma_L
            \end{align*}}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{posterbox}

    \begin{posterbox}[name=box9,span=3,column=0,below=box7,boxheaderheight=2em]{6. Lochleibung \bfseries{(Senkniete)}}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        \begin{align*}
            P_B \le P_{V,LB}  & = P_{V,LB1} + P_{V,LB2} \\ 
            P_{V,LB1} & = d_R \cdot (s-t) \cdot  \sigma_{min} \\
            P_{V,LB2} & = d_R \cdot t \cdot \alpha \cdot  \sigma_{min} \\
            & \\
            \text{where} & \\
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_{V,LB} & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            P_{V,LB1}   & =  \text{Zylindrischer Teil}\\
            P_{V,LB2}   & =  \text{Konischer Teil} \\
            s & = \text{Blechdicke}\\
            t & = \text{Senktiefe}\\
            \alpha & = \text{Abminderungsfaktor}\\
            d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
            & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
            & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ (Vollniet)}\\
            \alpha & = \text{Abminderungsfaktor}
        \end{align*}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \vfill
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.06\textheight]{example-image-a}
                \centering
        \vfill
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.128\textheight]{example-image-a}
        \[\sigma_{min} = \min 
        \begin{cases}
        \sigma_{LB}\\
        1,5 \cdot \sigma_{L2}
        \end{cases}\]
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.31\linewidth}\centering
        \underline{\bfseries Nietrechnungstabelle}\\
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \textcolor{blue}{Lochleibung Dimensionierend}\\
        \textcolor{red}{Abscheren Dimensionierend}\\
        \textcolor{green}{Zu Geringe Blechdicke}
                \vfill
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth, height=0.167\textheight]{example-image-a}
        \end{minipage}
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this surely looks kind of nice. I'd like an even more minimalistic solution for this case though, but I'm sure that this knowledge will come in handy very soon.

Comment: Is there any reason why `baposter` is not available on CTAN?